# Uso do método resizeto() javascript

Tags: javascript, html

Vi um exemplo no MDN e tentei replicá-lo, porém não funciona, ou seja, não vejo a janela do navegador ser redimensionada dinamicamente. Ainda se usa tal método? está codificado corretamente? A minha intenção é iniciar uma página `HTML`já com um tamanho pré-definido de janela (programaticamente).

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
 <meta charset="UTF-8">
 <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
<button onclick="quarter()">Pressione aqui</button>

<script>
 function quarter() {
  window.resizeTo(
    window.screen.availWidth / 2,
    window.screen.availHeight / 2
  );
}
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Opa, esse método funciona Fernandes, mas somente em janelas que você mesmo instanciou:

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
 <head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Document</title>
 </head>
  <body>
   <button onclick="criarMinhaJanela()">Criar janela</button>
   <button onclick="quarter()">Redimensionar</button>

  <script>
   var minhaJanela = null;

   function quarter() {
    if (minhaJanela) {
     minhaJanela.resizeTo(
     minhaJanela.screen.availWidth / 2,
     minhaJanela.screen.availHeight / 2
     );
    } else {
     console.log("Não existe janela...");
    }
   }

   function criarMinhaJanela() {
    try {
     minhaJanela = window.open("", "", "width=100, height=100");
    }
    catch(e) {
     console.log(e);
    }
   }
  </script>

  </body>
 </html>
```

***Obs.:*** Não é possível criar janela aqui no stackoverflow, então não rola executar esse código aqui =)

Sobre criar uma página com tamanho pré-definido, infelizmente nunca vi algo assim.

Comment: Daniel, valeu muito pelo que já acrescentou! Esse detalhe do instanciamento!